# Point Tracking using Optical Flow

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, opticalflow

Hello I'm trying to apply point tracking to a scene.

Now I want to get the points only moving in horizontally. Anyone have any thoughts on this?
The arrays "Actual" and "nextfeature" contain the relevant x,y coordinates. I tried to get the difference from the two arrays, it did not work. I tried to get the optical flow using Farneback but it didn't gave me a satisfying result. I would really appreciate if anyone can give me any thoughts on how to get the points only moving in horizontal line.

thanks.

Here is the code.

```
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {


        PointF[][] Actual = new PointF[0][];

        if (Frame == null) 
        {

            Frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();

            Previous_Frame = Frame.Copy();

        }

        else
        {

            Image<Gray, byte> grayf = Frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

            Actual = grayf.GoodFeaturesToTrack(300, 0.01d, 0.01d, 5);


            Image<Gray, byte> frame1 = Frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            Image<Gray, byte> prev = Previous_Frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            Image<Gray, float> velx = new Image<Gray, float>(Frame.Size);
            Image<Gray, float> vely = new Image<Gray, float>(Previous_Frame.Size);



            Frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame().Resize(300,300,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_AREA);

            Byte []status;
            Single[] trer;
            PointF[][] feature = Actual;
            PointF[] nextFeature = new PointF[300];



            Image<Gray, Byte> buf1 = new Image<Gray, Byte>(Frame.Size);
            Image<Gray, Byte> buf2 = new Image<Gray, Byte>(Frame.Size);
            opticalFlowFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(prev.Size);

            Image<Bgr, Byte>  FlowFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(prev.Size);


            OpticalFlow.PyrLK(prev, frame1, Actual[0], new System.Drawing.Size(10, 10), 0, new MCvTermCriteria(20, 0.03d),
                     out nextFeature, out status, out trer);




            for (int x = 0; x < Actual[0].Length ; x++)
            {
                opticalFlowFrame.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(nextFeature[x].X, nextFeature[x].Y), 1f), new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);

            }

            new1 = old;
            old = nextFeature;

            Actual[0] = nextFeature;



            Previous_Frame = Frame.Copy();
            captureImageBox.Image = Frame;
            grayscaleImageBox.Image = opticalFlowFrame;


            //cannyImageBox.Image = velx;

            //smoothedGrayscaleImageBox.Image = vely;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First... I can only give you a general idea about this, not a code snippet...

Here's how you may do this:
*(One of the many possible approaches of tackling this problem)*

1. Take the zero-th frame and pass it through *goodFeaturesToTrack*. Collect the points in an array ...say, *initialPoints*.
2. Grab the (zero + one) -th frame. With respect to the points grabbed from step 1, run it through *calcOpticalFlowPyrLK*. Store the next points in another array ...say, *nextPoints*. Also keep track of *status* and *error* vectors.
3. Now, with *initialPoints* and *nextPoints* in tow, we leave the comfort of openCV and do things our way. For every feature in *initialPoints* and *nextPoints* (with *status* set to 1 and *error* below an acceptable threshold), we calculate the gradient between the points.
4. Accept only those point for horizontal motion whose angle of slope is either around 0 degrees or 180 degrees. Now... vector directions won't lie perfectly at 0 or 180... so take into account a bit of +/- threshold.

Repeat step 1 to 4 for all frames.

Going through the code you posted... it seems like you've almost nailed steps 1 and 2.

However, once you get the vector *nextFeature*, it seems like you're drawing circles around it. Interesting ...but not what we need.

Check if you can go about implementing the gradient calculation and filtering.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. I managed to do the steps you mentioned. I forgot to mention that I'm trying to develop an application where i can track the motion of objects when driving on road. So when I take a dash-cam video from a car, all the pixels of the frame come towards us when driving forword. and if a object moved horizontally in front of the vehicle some pixels will go ack ony those pixels this.

Comment: Ok. In that case, there might be many outliers in the filtered feature vectors.

Comment: In my code there two arrays called "old" and "nextFeature". both having points in previous frame and currant frame. but when i debug my program for example old[0] value is very high than nextFeature[0] value. I think it because some track point disappear as they go out from the frame. So i'm getting my angle from getting tangent of these two point. so angle would not be correct right?